# Merge files where some columns matched

Tags: awk

Match columns 1,2,3 in both files, if they are equal then.

For files where columns match write value of column 4 in file1 into file2
If there is not match then write NA

**file1**

```
31431 37150 100 10100
31431 37201 100 12100
31431 37471 100 14100
```

**file2**

```
31431 37150 100 14100
31431 37131 100 14100
31431 37201 100 14100
31431 37478 100 14100
31431 37471 100 14100
```

**Desired output:**

```
31431 37150 100 14100 10100
31431 37131 100 14100 NA
31431 37201 100 14100 12100
31431 37478 100 14100 NA
31431 37471 100 14100 14100
```

**I tried**

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[$1 $2 $3]=$4
  next
}
($1 in a){
  $1=a[$1]
  found=1
}
{
  $0=found==1?$0",":$0",NA"
  sub(/^...../,"&,")
  $1=$1
  found=""
}
1
' FS=" " file1 FS=" " OFS="," file2
```

Comment: What are you trying to do when setting FS in `FS=" " file1 FS=" " OFS="," file2`? You're setting OFS to `,` and doing some additional hard-coding of commas in your code but there's no sign of any commas in your expected output. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk '      {k=$1 FS $2 FS $3} 
     NR==FNR {a[k]=$4; next} 
             {$(NF+1)=k in a?a[k]:"NA"}1' file1 file2

31431 37150 100 14100 10100
31431 37131 100 14100 NA
31431 37201 100 14100 12100
31431 37478 100 14100 NA
31431 37471 100 14100 14100
```

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1,$2,$3]=$NF;next} {print $0,($1,$2,$3) in a?a[$1,$2,$3]:"NA"}' Input_file1  Input_file2
```

OR with creating a variable for fields as per Ed sir's comment.

```
awk '{var=$1 OFS $2 OFS $3} FNR==NR{a[var]=$NF;next} {print $0,var in a?a[var]:"NA"}' Input_file1  Input_file2
```

Output will be as follows.

```
31431 37150 100 14100 10100
31431 37131 100 14100 NA
31431 37201 100 14100 12100
31431 37478 100 14100 NA
31431 37471 100 14100 14100
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code now.

```
awk '
{
  var=$1 OFS $2 OFS $3              ##Creating a variable named var whose value is first, second ansd third field of current lines of Input_file1 and Input_file2.
}
FNR==NR{                            ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when first Input_file1 is being read.
  a[var]=$NF                        ##Creating an array named a whose index is variable var and value is $NF of curent line.
  next                              ##next keyword will skip all further lines from here.
}
{
  print $0,var in a?a[var]:"NA"     ##Printing current line value and along with that printing either value of a[var] or NA based upon if var present in array a then print a[var] else print NA.
}'  Input_file1  Input_file2        ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```